# WSImport doesn't appear to be working with was8.5 JAXWS

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

I run the following command

```
wsimport -s ..\Code\app\src\main\java http://localhost:9080/shortbus/ShortbusService/ShortbusService.wsdl
```

This runs and generates code, however, when I try to compile given the new code I get...

```
...\ShortbusService_Service.java:[43,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.w
s.WebServiceFeature[])
location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
```

I tried explicitly adding the jaxws-api.jar and rt.jar but neither seemed to work. can someone help with what I am missing?

**Update**

If I manually edit to (notice the comments)...

```
public ShortbusService_Service(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    //super(__getWsdlLocation(), SHORTBUSSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), SHORTBUSSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public ShortbusService_Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SHORTBUSSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public ShortbusService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    //super(wsdlLocation, SHORTBUSSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    super(wsdlLocation, SHORTBUSSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public ShortbusService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public ShortbusService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    //super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}
```

It compiles but I would rather not do this.

Comment: You might try the WebSphere forum: http://ibm.biz/websphere-forum

Answer (score 1):

The code that's being generated by WAS 8.5's `wsimport` will generate code that is compatible with JAX-WS 2.2, because WAS 8.5 supports JAX-WS 2.2.

It seems that you are trying to compile your code against JAR files that represent an earlier version of JAX-WS, such as 2.0 or 2.1 (the `Service` constructor receiving "`features`" was added in JAX-WS 2.2).

So, you have two options:

1. Change your IDE settings (if you're using RAD, you'll probably have to migrate to a later RAD version) so your project compiles against the WAS 8.5 runtime; or
2. Use the `-target` switch for `wsimport`, providing the value `2.1` or `2.0`. That will generate code that can be compiled against older versions of JAX-WS.